# What is this overlay tile effect called, and how do I do it in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Does anyone know what the common name of this overlay effect is.  Can you recommend any tutorials on how to do this effect in photoshop?

Answer (score 2):

The effect is called a Geometric Overlay. As for tutorials, [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOS6Qotb_v0) is my favorite.

In case of link rot, search youtube for "geometric overlay tutorial photoshop" and I'm sure you'll find many other great tutorials.